# Cannot Display Json Array values from JSONData

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, http

I am trying to display JsonArray values from JSONData 
**JSON DATA**

> {"error":{"group_name":["The group name has already been taken."]}}

**Here is my Code**

```
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
 Log.d("Checking Login", responseStr);
 JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("group_name");
    for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    }
```

I am getting Exception Like this 
 **org.json.JSONException: No value for group_name**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`error` is nested `JSONObject` containing your `JSONArray`

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    JSONObject json1 = json.getJSONObject("error");
    //                                  ^^^^^ fetch nested JSON
     JSONArray jsonArray = json1.getJSONArray("group_name");
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
           // JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); error
           // jsonArray has no JSONOBJECT but it has String
        }
```

Note : your `group_name` JSONArray has no `jsonObjects` instead it has only a single `String` as per the example you showed so `jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)` will result in an exception.

---

```
{"error":{"group_name":["The group name has already been taken."]}}
                        |---------------String-----------------|
                       |---------------JSONOArray---------------|
         |-----------------Nested JSONOBJECT---------------------|
|------------------------JSONOBJECT-------------------------------|
```

---

So you have only `String` in you `JSONArray` so use [`optString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.json/json/20080701/org/json/JSONArray.java#JSONArray.optString%28int%29) to fetch your `String`

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
    JSONObject json1 = json.getJSONObject("error");
    //                                  ^^^^^ fetch nested JSON
     JSONArray jsonArray = json1.getJSONArray("group_name");
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
           String str = jsonArray.optString(i);
        }
```

Comment: I am getting this -  org.json.JSONException: Value error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Can u suggest me right way Json data for this? Group_name values should be arrays.

Comment: @DevTamil either you have to send `Group_name` containing `jsonobjects` or use `optString` to parse your current JSON response

Comment: I am debugging it. It's jumping to catch before starting the loop when it reaches the line JSONARRAY.

Comment: Working Great, Thanks @Pavneet Singh

Comment: @DevTamil i am glad that i could help  , happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Where **"error"** will go parse like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
JSONObject jsonError = json.getJSONObject("error");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonError.getJSONArray("group_name");
for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get string by this way

```
for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
       String groupName = jsonArray.optString(i);
    }
```